# Angular scroll directive

Tags: angularjs, events, angularjs-directive, responsive-design, ng-class

I try to create a directive with two params, class and pageYOffset. I would like to check the scrolling position of my element and add a class name if the pageYOffset is bigger than the number in the attr. Somehow I cant't trigger the class changes.

**HTML**

```
<div scroll offset="1500" ng-class="{active : scrollClass}"></div>
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('scroll', function($window) {
    return {
        scope: {
          offset: "@offset"
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
                if (this.pageYOffset >= scope.offset) {
                    scope.scrollClass = true;
                }
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: my guess is because you are defining a separate scope in your directive. the main div is using the parent scope, so the variable never changes in the parent scope, only in the directive scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are using isolated class, your directive scope is different scope than you controller scope, controller scope will not get inherited to directive scope because `scope: {..}`, As you want to change flag of parent scope you need to pass that value inside your directive with `=` which will perform two way binding as inner scope variable change will affect to the parent scope variable value.

**Makrup**

```
<div scroll offset="1500" scroll-class="scrollClass" ng-class="{active : scrollClass}"></div>
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('scroll', function($window) {
    return {
        scope: {
          offset: "@offset",
          scrollClass: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function(event) {
                if (element.pageYOffset >= scope.offset) {
                    //this will change the parent scope variable value to true
                    scope.scrollClass = true;
                }
                scope.$apply(); //need full to run digest cycle
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Just a slightly problem with the offset. I put two div in the page with `offset="1000"` and `offset="1500"` , and both happened on 1500.

Comment: could you share what element are used in directive? could you paste both directive elements here

Comment: `<div scroll offset="1000" scroll-class="scrollClass" ng-class="{active : scrollClass}"></div>` and 
`<div scroll offset="1500" scroll-class="scrollClass" ng-class="{active : scrollClass}"></div>`. And the directive exactly the same like yours.

Comment: you can use same variable for both directive `scrollClass` they both should be different..change this to  `<div scroll offset="1000" scroll-class="scrollFirstClass" ng-class="{active : scrollFirstClass}"></div>` and `<div scroll offset="1500" scroll-class="scrollSecondClass" ng-class="{active : scrollSecondClass}"></div>` it should work now

Comment: @levipadre Thanks once again..Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like tihs:

```
app.directive('scroll', function($window) {
    return {
        scope: {
          offset: "@offset",
          toggleScroll: "&toggle"
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
                if (this.pageYOffset >= scope.offset) {
                    toggle();
                }
                //scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    }
});

<div scroll offset="1500" toggle-scroll="changeActiveClass()" ng-class="{active : scrollClass}"></div>
```

Then define changeActiveClass in your parent scope:

```
$scope.changeActiveClass = function() {
    $scope.scrollClass = !scrollClass;
}
```